# Is there a way to allow inheritance only for final classes in C++

Tags: c++, compile-time

I have a base class that I want to be inherited from **only** by classes marked as final (or classes that are not themselves inherited from).

The underlying idea is that I want to forbid inheritance from this class by other superclasses, at compile time.

For example:

```
class O { /* Some compile time check here */ };
class A final : O {}; // OK
class B : O {}; // Not OK
```

I know this could be done in class A by using something like:

```
if ( std::is_base_of<O,A>::value ) static_assert( std::is_final<A>::value );
```

But this would need to be written in every single class. I'd like this check to be in class O (but I don't know if that's even possible).

Thank you

Comment: Put this before the class: `// Only inherit from O by classes that are final`

Comment: I can't see why this is desirable. What's wrong with sub-subclasses?

Comment: Please forget java

Comment: @Justin This is a tricky case, but basically the base class has a tool that perform a stream operation on the object. If the object is a sub-subclass and that it calls the subclass method within the stream operation, it can mess with the base class internal state. As I cannot prevent the dev to call the parent method from a child one, I thought enforcing inheritance on final would be good

Comment: If you think you need this, you have probably missed something or made some poor design choices.

Comment: @super I'm working with a lib that was designed that way. I could indeed rewrite the entire lib, but it's another piece of work that I'll tackle when I get time

Comment: @DimitriBouche I'm having a hard time imagining any sort of scenario where this would be relevant, but I guess most things are possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CRTP and std::is_final together.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename CRTP>
class Base {
public:
    ~Base() {
        static_assert( std::is_final<CRTP>::value );
    }
};

// This will trip a compile time static_assert when the class is instantiated.
class Derived : Base<Derived> { 
};

class DerivedAndFinal final : Base<DerivedAndFinal> {
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    (void)d;
    DerivedAndFinal daf;
    (void)daf;
}
```

Comment: Do note that not the class declaration, but the declaration of its instances trip a compile-time error.

Comment: Also, it's likely that you'd want to make the destructor virtual. That's of course debatable. Like most other things in C++

Comment: This can be easily bypassed by specializing the destructor. But then again it is complete nonsense to want this feature.

Comment: @para bypass? We probably only want to warn devs in case they make a mistake. It's possible to bypass this by removing the assertion or doing `#define static_assert(x)`. No one is really policing anyone.

Comment: What does (void)d; and (void)dad; do?

Comment: @Zebrafish Nothing, it just suppresses warnings about unused variables.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert What mistake are you trying to warn devs about? How is the structure of their implementation your concern?

Comment: @para Don't ask me, it's not my design. In the eyes of the designer of `Base`, having a non-final subclass is a mistake and they'd like to warn about that.

Comment: @para you can read my answer to Justin above for more details, but basically if my class O has a method M, allowing hierachical calls within M's overriden method can mess with O's state. M is meant to be called per object and performs sensitive stream operation. I don't allow nested stream operations.

Comment: @DimitriBouche you can also generalize this into something like an interface `IOnlyFinalSubclasses` https://godbolt.org/z/2AyuAH

Comment: Note that this works only if the template parameter is the derived class, which is not enforced by the compiler.

Comment: Also note that if the template parameter is the derived class, the derived classes no longer have a common base class. This limits some of the benefits of polymorphism. (Whether or not this limitation is important depends on the broader context.)